# how to set the members of a property?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a property for a vector like this

```
    public Vector2 TestVector
    {
        get { return testvector; }

        set
        {
            testvector = value;

        }
    }
```

the Vector2 has members X and Y.

When I want to set the property.x and property.y to values, it does not work

```
// this does not work
TestVector.X = 10;
```

how do I fix this?

edit: I see I am getting answers saying it's a struct, but really I have a made up class called dVector2, which is a class type not a struct, and I use that. I only put vector2 here for simplicity, but that backfired.

Comment: For the explanation "it does not work" the only advice is "so fix it *somehow*". Any particular exception? Or VS just says you "I won't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution nobody mentioned is to just make an accessor method for the X and the Y of each vector you have.

```
Public float TestVectorX
{
    get { return TestVector.X; }
    set { TestVector.X = value; }
}

Public float TestVectorY
{
    get { return TestVector.Y; }
    set { TestVector.Y = value; }
}
```

Adds a little more code but doesn't have the extra memory of declaring a new vector every time or the lost encapsulation from making it completely public.

Answer (score 5):

[`Vector2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx) is a struct (value-type). So here is what is happening when you attempt `TestVector.X = 10`:

```
{
    Vector2 temp = get_TestVector();   // copy is made during return from
                                       // hidden call to property getter method

    temp.X = 10;                       // modifying the copy

                                       // copy is gone
}
```

The net result is that **nothing happens**.

The unfortunate solution is:

```
TestVector = new Vector2 { X = 10, Y = TestVector.Y };
```

Another solution, which may be appropriate in your case, is to simply make `TestVector` a public field, instead of a property:

```
public Vector2 TestVector;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathon beat me to pointing out that you have a struct.

I would add that it is unwise, generally speaking, to have a *mutable* struct.  That leads to all kinds of complications due to value semantics.

Once a *struct* gets it's initial values, they should be unchangeable (i.e. no public setters, etc).

> If you use a C# struct, it should be immutable.  Mutable structs cause all kinds of nasty problems; don’t do it.  If I had to design the C# language over, I’d say that mutable structs would have to be marked with the ‘mutable’ keyword.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaybaz_ms/archive/2004/06/10/152748.aspx

Comment: Blame the XNA framework. But this same problem exists in the [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) structure, etc.

Comment: You are right that *generally* speaking mutable structs are best avoided. However in a game development context (like XNA), it is a necessary evil - usually for performance reasons (we can't go around creating heap objects all willy-nilly, plus we work a lot with buffers packed in a particular way).

Comment: Mutable structs are not "evil" if you take the time to fully appreciate their semantics.  It's just that they behave much differently than the average developer would expect, which causes problems.  I read a blog post about a design discussion for a key part of the .NET Framework that went through a similar performance discussion.  It was related to thread signaling, but I don't recall the exact context or the link.  Their bottom line was the same... if you need the last ounce of performance, use structs where appropriate and make sure everyone working on the code truly understands them.